# Количество открытых сокетов в windows 7 x64

Tags: сокеты, windows-7

Есть ли ограничение на кол-во открытых сокетов в этой ОС?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настоящее время нет фиксированного ограничения на количество одновременно открытых сокетов в любых современных версиях Windows. Реальное ограничение определяется количеством доступных ресурсов: пока возможность есть сокеты открываются. Поскольку каждый сокет занимает какое-то количеств памяти, процессора и ввода-вывода, то при исчерпании этих ресурсов сокеты перестанут работать. Если считать на основе невыгружаемого пула (где выделяется память для сокетов), то для обычной современной машины будет порядка 100 000 сокетов: пул может занимать гигабайты, а сокет десятки килобайт.